# Hint how to proceed to prove convergence of the senquence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $1\leq x_1\leq x_2 \leq 2$ and $x_{n+2} = \sqrt {x_{n+1}x_n} , n \in N$ Show that $x_n$ converges.

I got the value for $x_n$ as
$x_n = \frac{\sqrt{x_1}}{\sqrt{x_{n-1}}}x_2$ , please guide how to proceed further

Comment: Hi, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that also identifies the limit. Write $x_n=x_1(x_2/x_1)^{y_n}$, so that
$$y_{n+2}=\frac{y_{n+1}+y_n}{2} \tag{*}$$ for $n \ge 1$. Looking for a solution to this recursion of the form $\lambda^n$, we see that $\lambda^2=\frac{\lambda+1}{2}$, so $\lambda \in \{1, -1/2\}$. The vector space of sequences that solve $(*)$ is two dimensional, and is spanned by the constant sequence $(1,1,\ldots)$ and  the geometric sequence $(-1/2)^n$. Using the initial conditions  $y_1=0\,$ and $\, y_2=1$, we obtain that
$$y_n=\frac{1-(-1/2)^{n-1}}{3/2}\,.$$
Thus $y_n \to 2/3$ and $x_n \to x_1^{1/3} x_2^{2/3}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I wrote the answer before your second comment appeared, sorry.